# Do all stylesheets for the same site have to contain all the same properties, just with different values in order to work?

Tags: css, media-queries, stylesheet

I wrote a media CSS for mobile, and without the main stylesheet (desktop), it looks how I want on my device, but when I include the main stylesheet, it looks wonky on my device, almost as if it's taking properties from both sheets. Is it because I don't have all of the same properties for all of the selectors in both stylesheets?

Comment: Yes, it takes (and overrides) styles from both (bit more complicated to put in one phrase). Usually you create first the *Desktop* website and than you move step by step to smaller screen devices and orientations. Or, you detect the device and just serve the desired styles file.

Comment: No, not too late, it's an extremely small site, im just trying to position a couple images differently between desktop and mobile. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Means now you'll have to do what every front-end developer do, and that's clearing dirt from the `F5` button. Yes, you need to override in every `media` rule the desired element with the needed styles for that media type. (If you managed to use `!important` once or less... you've done a really good job!)

Comment: Well, just learned a new rule.